# Change email address provided at registration on stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

I have searched Stack Overflow, Stack Exchange, Super User, and didn't find anywhere an option to change my email address. Is there a way to do so? The email address I have provided at registration will be deleted today, therefore I have to change my login details on all sites.

Comment: Off-topic. Use the help below from Jeff Zeitlin though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might find [this Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) useful. It explains how to add additional email addresses/logins to your StackExchange account. You should also be able afterward to remove old, unused/unavailable email addresses/logins once the new ones are verified.

Comment: That is a good link, but including a few words of explanation would make your answer much better.

Comment: @music2myear - Point taken. Edited.

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlib Thank you very much! Yes, I have seen that page, but somehow didn't understand that I can enter a new email address without logging in with a Facebook account, or other social network accounts. Done.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Interesting: I did add new email address, and clicked on "remove" next to the previous email address. But today when I tried to log in using my new email address, I was "told" that such address is not registered. But I have logged in using the old one, which was supposed to be deleted. Something's not right. This means that I can't change the primary email address, but it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Vitale - You may need to take that up with the StackExchange people; I'm not one of them - I haven't actually had to change my login/email with SE, so I'm just going by what I read.

Comment: @Vitale: Did you check your email account (mailbox)?  Did you get an email from Stack Exchange?  Did you read it and do what it says?  Maybe Stack Exchange is waiting for you to complete the registration process for the new address before it actually disables the old one.

Comment: @Scott I am a bit surprised by your questions ) Of course, I check my email )

Comment: @Vitale: Sorry, but it's easy to imagine that a person juggling two email accounts might go for a day without checking *both* of them.  Sometimes people overlook the obvious.

Comment: @Scott I believe I have mentioned that the previous one is deleted, it doesn't exist anymore, hence no jugging ) Also mail clients solve any possible juggling issues )